# Unity LifeTime manager for Quartz.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container, quartz.net

I'm trying to use Quartz.Net in a asp.NET MVC application. I'm using Unity as DI, with `PerRequestLifeTimeManager`.

Quartz.Net, however, doesn't work with `PerRequestLifeTimeManager` because, well, it doesn't have a request to begin with. Any dependency I try to resolve with it returns null.

I've created a class like an adapter to use two life time managers depending on the context as following:

```
class CustomLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
{
    private readonly string _key = "CustomLifetimeManagerKey" + Guid.NewGuid();
    private readonly PerResolveLifetimeManager _perResolveLifetimeManager = new PerResolveLifetimeManager();

    private bool IsWebContext => HttpContext.Current != null;

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return IsWebContext 
            ? HttpContext.Current.Items[_key] 
            : _perResolveLifetimeManager.GetValue();
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        if (IsWebContext)
            HttpContext.Current.Items[_key] = newValue;
        else
            _perResolveLifetimeManager.SetValue(newValue);
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        if (IsWebContext)
            HttpContext.Current.Items[_key] = null;
        else
            _perResolveLifetimeManager.RemoveValue();
    }
}
```

I've tried `PerThreadLifetimeManager`, it executes fine for the first time, then the subsequent executions fails with the message

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been
>   disposed.

I've tried changing to `PerResolveLifeTimeManager`, but it fails with

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker

My job is pretty straightforward, similar to the following:

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
class MyJob 
{
    IFooRepository _fooRepository;
    IBarRepository _barRepository;
    public MyJob(IFooRepository fooRepository, IBarRepository barRepository)
    {
        _fooRepository = fooRepository;
        _barRepository = barRepository;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var foos = _fooRepository.Where(x => !x.Processed);

        foreach(var foo in foos)
        {
            var bar = _barRepository.Where(x => x.Baz == foo.Baz);
            foo.DoMagic(bar);
            foo.Processed = true;
            _fooRepository.Save(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

And my job factory is

```
public class UnityJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityJobFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (IJob)_container.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {

    }
}
```

How do I correctly manage dependency life time in a Quartz job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this to work long time ago with simpleinjector.
This was with an older version of Quartz though, hope it can still help

You need to create a custom LifetimeScope

```
public class LifetimeScopeJobDecorator : IJob
{
    private readonly IJob _decoratee;
    private readonly Container _container;

    public LifetimeScopeJobDecorator(IJob decoratee, Container container)
    {
        _decoratee = decoratee;
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
            using (_container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                _decoratee.Execute(context);
            }
    }
}
```

That you call into your job factory

```
public class SimpleInjectorJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly Container _container;

    public SimpleInjectorJobFactory(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
        _container.Verify();
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
            IJobDetail jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
            Type jobType = jobDetail.JobType;
            var job = (IJob)_container.GetInstance(jobType);
            return new LifetimeScopeJobDecorator(job, _container);
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize your custom Quartz Container

```
public static class QuartzScheduler
{
    private static Container _quartzContainer { get; set; }

    private static void Initialize()
    {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IUnitOfWork, SqlUnitOfWork>();
        container.Register<ILogger, NLogLogger>();


        //To enable lifetime scoping, please make sure the EnableLifetimeScoping extension method is called during the configuration of the container.
        container.EnableLifetimeScoping();
        container.Verify();
        _quartzContainer = new Container();

        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        _quartzContainer.RegisterSingle<IJobFactory>(() => new SimpleInjectorJobFactory(container));
        _quartzContainer.RegisterSingle<ISchedulerFactory>(schedulerFactory);
        _quartzContainer.Register<IScheduler>(() =>
        {
            var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
            scheduler.JobFactory = _quartzContainer.GetInstance<IJobFactory>();
            return scheduler;
        }
        );
        _quartzContainer.Verify();
```

Start the scheduler

```
    public static void StartJobs()
    {
        Initialize();

            //Ask the scheduler factory for a scheduler
            IScheduler scheduler = _quartzContainer.GetInstance<IScheduler>();
            scheduler.Start();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Castle.Windsor and Quartz.Net. The only applicable way i found was a ScopedLifetime, but you have to control the Scope by yourself. If a new Request comes in, open a scope and all service will be resolved in this scope (the so called UnitOfWork ;)) and when the request ends, close it.

The job handling is a little bit more trickier. But you have two ways to solve that. For both ways you need a Factory that can start scopes.

1. Your Job gets a Factory in the constructor and in `Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)` the factory starts a scope, resolves your service (repositories...) executes whatever the job does and closes the scope. A `using(Factory.BeginScope())` works great for this. the downside of this is, it is considered as bad practice because of using the service locator pattern.

   ```
   public class MyJob
   {
       private readonly Factory Factory;

       public MyJob(Factory factory)
       {
           Factory = factory;
       }

       public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
       {
           using (Factory.BeginScope())
           {
               var repo = Factory.Create<IFooRepository>();
               // Do stuff

               Factory.Release(repo);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Your Job gets a Factory or something that can start a scope and your service as function like: `Func<IFooRepository> repositoryFunc`. Then in your `Execute` method, start the scope (again with a using) and invoke your `repository`, it will return your real repository in that scope and you can work with it like you want. This should be the best way. Please note, that this is not considered as Service Locator Pattern, because you give your job the `Func<>` for the service and you just control the scope.

   ```
   public class MyJob
   {
       private readonly Factory Factory;
       private readonly Func<IFooRepository> RepositoryFunc;

       public MyJob(Factory factory, Func<IFooRepository> repositoryFunc)
       {
           Factory = factory;
           RepositoryFunc= repositoryFunc;
       }

       public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
       {
           using (Factory.BeginScope())
           {
               var repo = RepositoryFunc();
               // Do Stuff
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**The Problem**

1. PerThreadLifetimeManager

   > The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

   This comes because Quartz uses a MainThread and per default a ThreadPool with 10 Threads. All Jobs are created in the MainThread and then executed in a free thread from the pool. If you start a job, the DBContext is bound to the MainThread. When you start another job, then there is already a DBContext bound to this Thread, no matter if it is disposed or closed and the LifeTimeManager will resolve this already used context. <s>If you start your Job the first time, the Thread is new and you current DBContext is bound to this Thread. When you start the next job and it executes in the same Thread, then there was always a DBContext bound to this Thread. The LifeTimeManager resolves this allready used context, but you can't use it, because its closed.</s>
2. PerResolveLifeTimeManager

   > An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

   This issue comes from EF. Each service that you resolve gets an new Scope, even if you resolve different services with the same constructor. This results in that every Repository you use, have its own DBContext. And EF forbids to use different DBContexts with the same entity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still haven't fully grasped how to implement this factory yet, but I'll work on it tomorrow. If you have any example, it would be great.  Is it possible to open and close those scopes inside my UnityJobFactory? This way I could make the job ignorant to the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Quartz.Unity nuget package https://github.com/hbiarge/Quartz.Unity, this unity package has a decent implementation of ScopedLifetime.

In addition to the above nuget package, if you use multiple unity container instances and pass the lifetimemanager as a delegate, it will allow you to properly handle the disposable types such as DBContext for each quartz job as well as for each http request.

You have to setup a separate IUnityContainer instance for the asp.net mvc / web api and another instance of IUnityContainer for Quartz scheduler.

Here is a full working sample 
https://github.com/vinodres/DITestingWithQuartz

If you look at QuartzStartup.cs, I have used it to initialize Quartz Scheduler. For simplicity purposes, lets assume IHelloService is a disposable type and it must be disposed at the end of each job as well as at the end of each http request. Here I am creating a separate instance of 
IUnityContainer assigned to QuartzContainer and added new extension called QuartzUnityExtention from Quartz.Unity nuget package. Also invoked a .Configure extension method that I created inside another file called unityconfig.cs. This method take Func as a parameter. This parameter allows you to pass different life time manager instances based on the execution path.

Here is **QuartzStartup.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DiTestingApp.QuartzStartup))]
namespace DiTestingApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class QuartzStartup
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(QuartzStartup));
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the hangfire container.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> QuartzContainer = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.AddNewExtension<QuartzUnityExtension>();
            container.Configure(() => new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            Log.Info("Quartz Startup Intitializing...");
            var container = QuartzContainer.Value;
            InitScheduler(container);
            Log.Info("Quartz Startup Intialization Complete...");

            var properties = new AppProperties(app.Properties);
            var cancellationToken = properties.OnAppDisposing;
            if (cancellationToken != CancellationToken.None)
            {
                cancellationToken.Register(() =>
                {
                    QuartzContainer.Value.Dispose();
                    Log.Info("Quartz container disposed (app pool shutdown).");
                });
            }
        }

        private void InitScheduler(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            try
            {
                var scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
                scheduler.Start();

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloWorldJob>().Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(20).RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

A similar setup I have for asp.net mvc / web api dependency resolver configuration. I created a file called UnityMvcActivator.cs, here when I call .Configure extension method, I am passing PerRequestLifetimeManager.

**UnityMvcActivator.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Common.Logging;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(DiTestingApp.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(DiTestingApp.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Shutdown")]

namespace DiTestingApp.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.</summary>
    public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(UnityWebActivator));
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the hangfire container.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> WebContainer = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.Configure(() => new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            Log.Info("Web api DI container intializing.");
            var container = WebContainer.Value;

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));

            var resolver = new Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
            Log.Info("Web api DI container intialization complete.");
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            Log.Info("Web api DI container disposing.");
            var container = WebContainer.Value;
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Now comes the part where you register your types with IUnityContainer. Here is the implementation of configure method inside UnityConfig.cs. Here I have registered IHelloService to use the disposableLifetimeManager delegate. When the delegate is invoked, a proper lifetime manager is supplied depending on your execution path. It will be PerRequestLifetimeManager, if IHelloService is used with in context of asp.net mvc / web api. And it will be HierarchicalLifetimeManager if it is used inside a Quartz Job.

**UnityConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using DiTestingApp.Models;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Quartz;
using Testing.Scheduler;

namespace DiTestingApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
    /// </summary>
    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container"></param>
        /// <param name="disposableLifetimeManager"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IUnityContainer Configure(this IUnityContainer container, Func<LifetimeManager> disposableLifetimeManager )
        {

            container.RegisterType<IJob, HelloWorldJob>();
            container.RegisterType<IHelloService, HelloService>(disposableLifetimeManager());
            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

HierarchicalLifetimeManager is used for Quartz execution path, so that any disposable types will be properly disposed at the end of each job.

If Quartz.Unity implementation is not sufficient for your use cases, you can always customize it further.